# Convert Unix Date and Time to Local Time with JavaScript (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unix

I'm trying to convert unix timestamp to local date in a react project. Below is the function that I'm using:

```js
function convertDate(unixDate) {
        const d = new Date(unixDate * 1000);
        const day = d.toLocaleString(d.getDate())
        return(day);
    }
```

The date I'm getting is not acurate. For example is we run convertDate(1657745369979.82) we should get the date '07/13/2022 8:49:29 PM'. However the date that I'm actually getting is '11/10/54501, 8:59:39 AM'

Comment: remove * 1000 because new browser date already support accepting unix timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you multiplying by 1000 ?
This works just fine

```
new Date(1657745369979.82).toLocaleString() => '14/07/2022, 02:19:29'
```

which is the same as

```
Convert epoch to human-readable date and vice versa
1657745369979.82
 Timestamp to Human date  [batch convert]
Supports Unix timestamps in seconds, milliseconds, microseconds and nanoseconds.
Assuming that this timestamp is in milliseconds:
GMT: Wednesday, July 13, 2022 8:49:29.979 PM
Your time zone: Thursday, July 14, 2022 2:19:29.979 AM GMT+05:30
Relative: A day ago
```

from https://www.epochconverter.com/

If there's more that you want, this old thread should also help
[Convert a Unix timestamp to time in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you. This works fine in the console, but in my react app, I get "Invalid Date" when I remove *1000

Comment: Interesting.. i tried this on a react app and it worked fine    
<div>
          {`${new Date(1657745369979.82).toLocaleString()}`}
</div>
Maybe you are fetching the date from an api and its not formatted properly

Comment: I've found a solution although I have no idea why it works. 

return new Date(unixDate * 1).toLocaleString()

multiplying the date by 1 makes it work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not need to multiply the timestamp by 1000.

Unix timestamps are often of this length: 1657831769, which would need to be multiplied by 1000 (https://www.epochconverter.com/ is useful for testing conversions).

```
const unixDate = 1657745369979.82;
const d = new Date(unixDate);
console.log(d.toISOString());
```

Output: 2022-07-13T20:49:29.979Z

Comment: Thank you. This works fine in the console, but in my react app, I get "Invalid Date" when I remove *1000. Could it be because the unix date I'm getting is 13 digits instead of 10?

Comment: Sorry, I'm no expert in react, could be worth trying to remove the decimal places? E.g., 1657745369979 instead of 1657745369979.82